# How to update Firestore Timestamp to a future value

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We have a check-in and check-out component in our web app that simply uses firebase timestamps. However, we need the ability to edit those timestamps in the event someone makes a mistake.

checkInTimeStamp: fb.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp("17:00") simply returns the current time.

Instead of 17:00, what object do we need to pass through the function to get the correct timestamp?

Comment: Hey @Greg were you able to checkout my answer below? If yes and it worked out, you can accept/upvote it so others will know it's resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The [`serverTimestamp()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#servertimestamp) generates *current* timestamp on server side. You can use a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object instead to store a future date:

```
const futureDate = new Date();

// update date to future time
futureDate.setDate(futureDate.getDate() + 5);

db.document('col/doc').set({ checkInTimeStamp: futureDate })
```

Checkout other method like `setDate()` in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) docs.